# How to narrow custom number type by if condition in typescript

Tags: typescript

### Code

```js
type FingerType = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5;

function fingerFn(finger: FingerType) {
    console.log("finger : ", finger);
}

const digit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
if (0 < digit && digit < 6) {
    fingerFn(digit)
}
```

In this situation, typescript show error `Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FingerType'`

How to make typescript compiler ensure that `digit` is `FingerType` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common way to solve this would be to use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-type-assertions).

```
const isFingerType = (n: number): n is FingerType => 0 < digit && digit < 6

const digit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
if (isFingerType(digit)) {
    fingerFn(digit)
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=14#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgOwOYQE4BVzQLxQIxQA%20UATEVAMzkAs5ArANwCwAUKwGYCuCAxsHAHsEUdohSoYCABSjkaAFywxaTJACUUAN6souqDyEBnAQBsIAOhMCkUgESzxURbYA0I5ajXMWAX1b%20WAwRDYCg4Q3g5DCwoXCkERQROAFsAIzQ1RLDDJSjVHAA%20KAAGKAAeKAATOCQ4UIAyeqqauvKoADYAoJDm2tDcAFkAQ2AAC3N2KwFUKWGx81QhhEqBZKkNACp8Yq9WOHYoKXDI8Xypar61DW0WPXcoyXOW4DVWPxYgA)

Comment: Nice explanation. Just a side note so one won't get wrong expectations - the compiler doesn't actually enforce the value fits this type - the type guard expression may be wrong (e.g., `digit <= 10`) and it will not complain. The same happens with `fingerFn(digit as FingerType)` in the original code.